# AWS S3 : upload only the file change (delta)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, cloud

Is it possible to upload only the file change (delta) with AWS S3 (using the Node.JS SDK or Pre-signed URL) ?

Comment: There is one option that is theoretically possible, but it depends very heavily on the nature of the delta and your ability to calculate it yourself.  For example, for a file > 5 MiB that only has data appended to the end, there is a set of advanced, low-level operations that could be leveraged to make this happen.  What's the nature of the delta and what's the motivation for this approach (since uploads are free)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That is not possible

For adding a Delta, you will have to fetch the object locally, add the delta and then upload back to s3