# Amazon S3 synch command uploads the entire modified file again or just the delta in the file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My system generate large log files continuously and I want to upload all the log files to Amazon S3. I am planning to use the s3 synch command for this. My system appens the logs in the same file until they are of about 50MB and then it create new log file. I understand that synch command will synch the modified local log file in s3 bucket, but I dont want to upload the entire log file when the file changes as the files are large and sending same data again and again will consume my data bandwidth.

So I am wondering if s3 synch command sends the entire modified file or just the delta in the file?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141078/aws-s3-upload-only-the-file-change-delta

Answer (score 1):

The documentation implies that it copies the whole updated files

```
Recursively copies new and updated files
```

Plus there would be no way to to do this without downloading the file from S3 which would effectively double the cost of an upload since you'd pay the download and upload costs.